Issues with Detecting Object Borders Due to Color or Transparency in OpenCV and Feret Measurements
-Object Detection: Due to the color or transparency of the items, the borders are not accurately detected using the background subtraction method.
-Measurements: This inaccuracy leads to incorrect Feret diameter measurements.
I'm working on a project where I need to detect and measure items in images. Each image contains a picture of an item, and I'm using the **subtraction **method in OpenCV (cv2) to remove the background and then using the imea library to calculate the maximum and minimum Feret diameters. However, I'm facing challenges with detecting the borders of the items, particularly due to their color or transparency.
Here is the code that I'm using (I'm running this in a Jupyter Notebook):
import cv2 as cv
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Clean up
plt.close('all')
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from tqdm import tqdm
import cv2  # Import OpenCV for image preprocessing
import feret  # Import the feret module

# Function to display images in Jupyter
def display_image(image, title='Image'):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

# Path to the folder containing images and the background image
image_folder = '.'
background_image_path = 'Main.jpeg'

# Load the background image
background_image = cv.imread(background_image_path, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
if background_image is None:
    print(f"Unable to load background image: {background_image_path}")
    exit(1)

# Convert background image to grayscale
background_gray = cv.cvtColor(background_image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Iterate through each file in the folder
for filename in os.listdir(image_folder):
    if filename.endswith('.jpeg') and filename != 'Main.jpeg':
        image_path = os.path.join(image_folder, filename)
        
        # Load the current image
        image = cv.imread(image_path, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
        if image is None:
            print(f"Unable to load image: {image_path}")
            continue

        # Convert current image to grayscale
        image_gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
        # Perform background subtraction
        fgMask = cv.absdiff(background_gray, image_gray)
        
        # Apply a threshold to get the binary image
        _, fgMask = cv.threshold(fgMask, 50, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    
        # Display the original image and the foreground mask
        display_image(cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB), title='Original Image')
        display_image(fgMask, title='Foreground Mask')

        # Plot Feret diameters on the preprocessed image
        feret.plot(fgMask)        
        # Calculate Feret diameters and angles
        maxf_length, minf_length, minf_angle, maxf_angle = feret.all(fgMask)
        
        # Print the results for the current image
        print(f"Filename: {filename}, Max Feret Length: {maxf_length}, Min Feret Length: {minf_length}")
        
    
        # result_path = os.path.join('path_to_save_results', f'fgMask_{filename}')
        # cv.imwrite(result_path, fgMask)

        # Pause to control the display in the notebook
        # This can be adjusted or removed as needed
        input("Press Enter to continue...")

# Clean up
plt.close('all')

# Optionally, print all results at the end
# for res in results:
#     print(f"Filename: {res['filename']}, Max Feret Length: {res['maxf_length']}, Min Feret Length: {res['minf_length']}")

Main(Background)
sample
sample
sample
sample
sample
more samples
Current Output
Are there alternative methods or preprocessing steps in OpenCV that could help in better isolating the items from the background?
Any advice, suggestions, or guidance on how to tackle these issues would be greatly appreciated.

@CrisLuengo I apologize for the confusion. I realize now that I posted the wrong script earlier; it was an outdated version that applied grayscale on the mask and didn't work as intended. I've updated my post with the correct script now. Sorry for any inconvenience this may have caused.

@CrisLuengo Isolating the middle object sounds like the correct path by I couldn't really figure out how. Also it would be great if you could share your version of the code after tweaking it as it will help me understand mroe your point of view . it seems like you're getting better results!

The first change I would make is taking the maximum difference for each pixel across the channels, rather than converting to grayscale. When converting to grayscale, different colors with a similar intensity will appear similar.
Next, lower the threshold. You picked 50 to ensure that there's no pixels found outside the object at all. Using a bit of filtering you can reduce the noise levels, and thus also reduce this threshold. Ideally the threshold is chosen such that your object is as solid as possible, that most object pixels are identified. You can then ignore other "objects" that appear because of noise and differences in the background intensity by looking only at the object in the middle of the field of view.
This is one way of doing so. I'm using DIPlib here, as I know it better than OpenCV, so it's faster for me to experiment (also, I'm an author).
import diplib as dip

bg = dip.ImageRead('7AqYQsRe.jpg')  # the background image
img = dip.ImageRead('3Kvw57Jl.jpg')

diff = dip.MaximumTensorElement(dip.Abs(img - bg))  # your fgMask_gray
diff = dip.MedianFilter(diff)  # a minimal amount of filtering
objects = diff > 10  # a random value that seems to do quite well

# Pick the object in the center of the field of view, the quick and dirty way:
objects = dip.Label(objects)
label = objects[objects.Size(0) // 2, objects.Size(1) // 2]
mask = objects == label

# Measure
msr = dip.MeasurementTool.Measure(+mask, features=['Feret'])
print(msr)
max_len, min_len, perm_min_len, max_angle, min_angle = msr[1]['Feret']

Note that dip.MedianFilter uses a circular mask with a diameter of 7 pixels by default. I have not tried to adjust this parameter. You could also try better noise filters. All filtering can affect the location of edges, heavier filtering will likely make your object smaller. But some filters are better at preserving the edge location than others. Linear filters will have the biggest impact. Be aware of this!
The thresholded image actually looks really good. We can use dip.AreaOpening() to remove the smaller dots, leaving only the true object. But I included the logic in the code above because it makes sense and is likely more robust. A better way to keep only the object in the center is to measure the centroid of each object, and picking the one where the centroid is closest to the center of the image:
import numpy as np

msr = dip.MeasurementTool.Measure(objects, features=['Center', 'Feret'])
best_dist = 1e7
best_obj = 0
center = np.asarray(objects.Sizes()) // 2
for obj in msr.Objects():
    dist = np.linalg.norm(np.asarray(msr[obj]['Center']) - center)
    if dist < best_dist:
        best_dist = dist
        best_obj = obj

max_len, min_len, perm_min_len, max_angle, min_angle = msr[best_obj]['Feret']


Edit 1: If the object is not always in the center of the image, you can for example look for the biggest object (using DIPlib, it's the 'Size' feature), or come up with some other feature that is meaningful in your application.

Edit 2: To measure only the largest object:
import diplib as dip

bg = dip.ImageRead('7AqYQsRe.jpg')  # the background image
img = dip.ImageRead('3Kvw57Jl.jpg')

diff = dip.MaximumTensorElement(dip.Abs(img - bg))  # your fgMask_gray
diff = dip.MedianFilter(diff)  # a minimal amount of filtering

objects = diff > 10  # a random value that seems to do quite well
objects = dip.Label(objects, mode='largest')  # the labeled image will have only one object in it
msr = dip.MeasurementTool.Measure(objects, features=['Feret'])
max_len, min_len, perm_min_len, max_angle, min_angle = msr[1]['Feret']


I've replied to your suggestion in an answer because i couldn't figure out how to add samples to the comment

@Agura I've added a comment to the answer.

is there a way to know if the feret calculation iswright or not using the diplib ?

@Agura. I've implemented it, it is always right. Look at the mask you put into the function, if the mask is right, you'll get the correct measurements for that mask. If you want to see what it does under the covers, you'll have to read the source code. Or you can read this blog post that I wrote when I first implemented the algorithm currently in DIPlib.

so it will always detect the items even if they're not centered ?

@Agura The detection happens when you threshold/binarize. In the binary image, we apply dip.Label() to do connected component analysis. You can look at the output of this if you like. Each connected component will now have a unique integer associated (the label or object ID). The measurement function will measure each of the objects (so all the pixels with a value of 1 will contribute to the measurements for object number 1, etc.). None of that process involves any guess work or unknowns. The only difficult part is determining a good threshold and filtering before and after the threshold.

I see. Thank you a lot for the help. Sadly, I'm still facing major problems due to the background not being the same for all pieces. I have more than 1,000 items to go through, and my team made a significant mistake by allowing lights to reflect on the background instead of using a uniform color. You have no idea how important this phase is for me to move on to the more serious one. Without a clean start, I cannot achieve good results. I wish I could meet you in person or something to show you the full data.

I guess here you have to decide whether the cost of developing a robust algorithm that handles all these cases is higher or lower than the cost of imaging all these pieces again, under better conditions. Or you can manually process each of the binarized images, fixing up the outline where it goes wrong.

Imagining all of the pieces required a full setup included 3 HD cameras and a lot of hand work so they left me with this lol, very fair.

Hello Cris again so I was tweaking your code a bit and I couldn't figure out the function that detects the biggest object rather than the one in the middle is there any possible way to do so ?

@Agura In the dip.MeasurementTool.Measure() call add 'Size' to the list of features, then pick the object with the largest size. Actually, you can simplify this by adding mode='largest' to the dip.Label call.

I see, thanks, it worked! I also have another question. I saved all the pictures after applying the subtraction and the mask. The results look great, and now I want to extract measurements from them. However, the code keeps returning errors, and the documentation site isn't very clear. Could you help me figure out the problem?
Here's the code I'm using:
img = dip.ImageRead(img_path) diff = dip.MaximumTensorElement(img) msr = dip.MeasurementTool.Measure(diff, features=['Feret']) max_len, min_len = msr[1]['Feret'][0], msr[1]['Feret'][1]  # Max and Min Feret diameters 

it keeps on returning "Maxinf" as value

@Agura the input to the measure function must be a labeled image. You need to binarize your diff and then apply the dip.Label function.

could u enlighten me to how ?

@Agura I've added code to the bottom of the answer.
